MergeSort implementation doesn't work correctly
I've been trying to implement MergeSort in Python from the book Introduction to Algorithms and I don't know why this version is not working correctly (it does compile but the list isn't sorted properly).
My code:
import math
def MergeSort(A,p,r):
    if(p>=r):
        return
    q=math.floor((p+r)/2)
    MergeSort(A,p,q)
    MergeSort(A,q+1,r)
    Merge(A,p,q,r)
def Merge(A,p,q,r):
    nL=q-p
    nR=r-q
    L=[0]*nL
    R=[0]*nR
    for i in range(0,nL):
        L[i]=A[p+i]
    for j in range(0,nR):
        R[j]=A[q+j]
    i=0
    j=0
    k=p
    while i < nL and j < nR:
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            A[k]=L[i]
            i=i+1
        else:
            A[k]=R[j]
            j=j+1
        k=k+1
    while i<nL:
        A[k]=L[i]
        i=i+1
        k=k+1
    while j < nR:
        A[k]=R[j]
        j=j+1
        k=k+1

A=[20,52,35,22,90,12,5]
MergeSort(A,0,len(A))
print(A)

the problem is this part:
    if(p>=r):
        return
    q=math.floor((p+r)/2)
    MergeSort(A,p,q)
    MergeSort(A,q+1,r)

when it isn't q+1 the recursion never ends but with q+1 it doesn't give correct output
the code that works:
import math

def MergeSort(A, p, r):
    if p < r - 1:
        q = (p + r) // 2
        MergeSort(A, p, q)
        MergeSort(A, q, r)
        Merge(A, p, q, r)

def Merge(A, p, q, r):
    nL = q - p
    nR = r - q
    L = [0] * nL
    R = [0] * nR
    for i in range(nL):
        L[i] = A[p + i]
    for j in range(nR):
        R[j] = A[q + j]
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = p
    while i < nL and j < nR:
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            A[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            A[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1
    while i < nL:
        A[k] = L[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1
    while j < nR:
        A[k] = R[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1

A = [20, 52, 35, 22, 90, 12, 5]
MergeSort(A, 0, len(A))
print(A)


I would like to have my version working because it's the most similar to the pseudocode from the book and also learn why this one isn't right since I'm only starting working with recursions.

I haven't read the whole thing, but the key question here seems to be: is r argument inclusive or not? If r is the right-hand side of what needs to be sorted (as opposed to the length of what needs to be sorted) then it seems that it should be called with MergeSort(A, 0, len(A) - 1).

Yeah I think @500-InternalServerError is right... Either r is a length or it is an index. Your code is probably mixing it up somewhere. Also: double check what convention your book follows on array indexing. If the book assume indexes start at 1 you will have to adjust.

Here is the correct version:
import math


def MergeSort(A, p, r):
    # only sort when upper index is greater than lower index
    if p < r:
        # calculate the middle point
        q = p + (r - p) // 2
        # process the left slice
        MergeSort(A, p, q)
        # process the right slice (from middle  + 1) obviously the middle point should be processed either in the left slice or the right slice
        MergeSort(A, q + 1, r)
    enter code here
#
        Merge(A, p, q, r)


def Merge(A, p, q, r):
    # the middle point is included with the left slice
    nL = q - p + 1
    # right slice don't have the middle point
    nR = r - q
    L = [0] * nL
    R = [0] * nR
    for i in range(nL):
        L[i] = A[p + i]
    # same here, right slice should be read from the original array shifter 1 position to the right
    for j in range(nR):
        R[j] = A[q + j + 1]
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = p
    while i < nL and j < nR:
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            A[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            A[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1
    while i < nL:
        A[k] = L[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1
    while j < nR:
        A[k] = R[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1


A = [20, 52, 35, 22, 90, 12, 5]
# last index is len(A)-1 not len(A)
MergeSort(A, 0, len(A) - 1)
print(A)


Please explain in your answer what the problem was with the asker's code, and what you have changed, and why it works with that change. Only providing working code is not helping the asker, as they already provided working code.

@trincot added some comments, hope it help.

In MergeSort we can see that with MergeSort(A,q+1,r) you add one to q to have the first argument represent the first index of the second partition. By consequence, with MergeSort(A,p,q) the last argument represents the last index that is part of the partition to sort, and not the first index after that partition.
This means you have two errors in Merge:

nL=q-p should be nL=q-p+1, because you want to count p as part of the left partition

R[j]=A[q+j] should be R[j]=A[q+j+1], because the right partition starts at q+1, not q.


And the main call should also be consistent with the meaning of the last argument:

MergeSort(A,0,len(A)) should be MergeSort(A,0,len(A)-1)

Although one could make other comments on your code, with these three changes it will work.
